# What is EastworldService running from the Play Store app?

Tags: google-play-store

I looked in on my running apps and my Play Store has 1 process but 20 services running: Play Detection Async services, Collection Dispatching services, Thunderbird Setting Injector service's, Device Connection watcher service, GCM service, Pending Intent Callback service, Context Manager service, Nearby Direct service, Cable Authenticator, Emergency Persistent, Lockscreen, Scheduler, Google Location Management, Local Accuracy Injector, ClearcutDebugDump, Local Persistent, and Nearby messages service.

[image]

Is this not a little odd? Please please someone help. My phone is driving me crazy

Answer (score 1):

The "Eastworld Service" is an integral part of the Google Mobile Services (GMS).

From it's code it seems for example to collects some device statistical data like app (un)installations, available Playstore updates, screen on-times, charging times...

BTW: The GMS core package also contains a "Westworld" service and other funny names. Also the Thunderbird service is mentioned here, seems to be related to Google Cloud Messaging (better known as Push Messaging system or "Firebase Messaging").